# Titanium app closes and shuts down at random

Tags: android, geolocation, titanium, appcelerator

I've confirmed this on Android 2.3.6 and 4.1.2 .. Can't say i did on iOS(Haven't had an extended test on it yet). But here's the deal:

I've got an app which sends it's current coordinates to a php service which saves it to a mysql database and sends a response(usually 1) back to the app as a result. It does this in a 5 second interval and does it in a way i want it to. So basically the app does a fine job. However; If i wait a while the complete app just CLOSES itself at random. It happened to me after 9 hours and 3 hours and there's no real reason to do so. The phone is just laying stationary on my desk basically.

Is there any known issue for titanium apps to just shut down without a crashreport/warning whatsoever?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you might be violating something about the way the mobile OS runs.  Maybe you have a memory leak and the device/emulator sees your app eating all the memory and force closes it.  I'm not sure what logs are available on devices to inform you about what just happened.  Maybe you'll see the app was closed by the device and a reason why.

Have you profiled your app?  I'm going to guess memory leak.

Comment: I've ran Instruments for the iOS version of the app and it doesn't really look like it's leaking apart from a timer(Made a post about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16011920/is-cfrunlooptimer-supposed-to-higher-in-living-column). I can only assume that the android version won't leak either than.

Comment: FWIW, I would never assume that because one thing happens in iOS, the same will be true for Android. Two very different development paradigms here.